# Call function multiple times from another function

Tags: solidity

It is possible to call a function from another function for example 2 times, like:

```
function go(uint _amount, uint _amount2, uint16 destChainId, uint16 destChainId2, bytes calldata _destination, bytes calldata _destination2) public payable {

SendToken(_amount, destChainId,  _destination);
SendToken(_amount2, destChainId2,  _destination2);
    
    }

function SendToken(uint _amount, uint16 destChainId, bytes calldata _destination) public payable  {
       //something do
}
```

So i want call "SendToken" 2 times by calling "go". If it possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - and your snippet already does that.

You can also call the target function multiple times using a loop

```
function go(uint[] calldata amounts, uint16[] calldata destChainIds, bytes[] calldata destinations) public payable {
    // TODO validate the length of inputs
    uint length = 2;
    for (uint i; i < length; i++) {
        SendToken(amounts[i], destChainIds[i], destinations[i]);
    }
}
```

---

Since your functions are `payable`, keep in mind that the `msg.value` is already set by the transaction sender and cannot be affected from the contract. So you might want to split the value between the calls.

For example if the user sends 1 ETH and you call `SendToken` 2 times, you might want to split the amounts and send tokens worth only 0.5 ETH from each of the internal calls.

Comment: Thanks, but i still got execution reverted... If i call SendToken direct from contract it works, but go functions not.... I'm trying to find out...

Comment: Can't reproduce your issue - it's executing correctly on my end when I pass the following parameters to your original function `go()`: `0, 0, 0, 0, [], []` Please provide steps to reproduce the error... It's also possible that the revert is caused by some code that you didn't share in the question (and replaced with "something do").

Comment: yes, it looks like this is a problem in my SendToken function, it can't work in parallel at the same time.